# How to help compiler do pipelining?

Tags: compilers, cpu-pipelines, c

I don't mean compiler flags for pipelining. I would like to program in a way that helps the compiler do optimizations using pipelining. I mean I want to order instructions in C in such a way that GCC (or other compiler) can easily pipeline my instructions. For example, if I have:

```
a+=b
c=a/b
d+=b
f+=b
```

Here, the last two 'add' operations would be pipelined, but not the first. I would turn it into:

```
a+=b
d+=b
f+=b
c=a/b
```

Notice that the three 'add' operations can be pipelined, but the floating point division cannot.

I want to know, is there more cases in which I can help the compiler do pipelining optimizations? What operations are the ones that can be generally pipelined in modern processors, and that compilers can recognize in code?

Comment: Please suggest a definition of [*pipelining*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining) to use with this question and upcoming answers. (In the first case, `a+=b;c=a/b+1; d+=b; f+=b` can (in case of the first two, must) be started synchronously.)

Comment: Compilers can and will optimize your code. And an out-of-order processor will reorder instructions into an optimal way anyway. For example, each core in your iPhone can have a few hundred instructions scheduled for execution and will pick whichever instructions are ready. Write instructions in the way that is most readable.